# Timed Out Response Not Logged In Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

We noticed today that a service we integrate with was timing out 15 seconds after making a request to one of our endpoints.  Their logs showed that the service retried immediately after and go a response fairly quickly <100ms.  We were trying to investigate the issue and grepped the apache access and error logs but were unable to find the request that apparently timed out.

We are trying to diagnose where the issue is and think the fact that we are not seeing it in apache might be the symptom of the underlying problem.  We'd appreciate any input on what this behavior might mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not seeing a request in your access logs, your server is not receiving the request, or is to busy to acknowledge it.  Likely culprits would be network issues, or cpu over-utilization on your server.  Set up an event logging tool on each end, and you should be able to find your issue easily.